# How can I create a nested TreeView for Windows 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

How can I create a nested TreeView for Windows 8.1 app , data will be bind at runtime using C#? There is no Treeview Control in Windows 8.1 Development.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use TreeView on Windows 8, the default style of hierarchical navigation on Windows 8 is by clicking items and using the back button to browse back (although Microsoft use TreeView on Microsoft official apps (for example Mail App) .

If you still want to use TreeView, There is a [TreeView control](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9c814f6c67c540adbd6952821a351d9ffa4d1d99#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView/TreeView.cs) in WinRT XAML Toolkit.